# Spring boot customised annotation configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am trying to create customised Spring boot annotation which will have all methods from @Transactional and will send event in case of specific exceptions while saving the Person object.

```
@DatabaseSloError(value = Exception.class)
public void saveUser(Person person) {
    personRepository.save(person);
}
```

Annotation looks like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional
public @interface DatabaseSloError {
    Class\<? extends Exception\> value();
}
```

Now I have created a processor which I assume will be triggered when applied method will have some exception. Here is the processor

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.learn.restapi.annotation.DatabaseSloError")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11)
public class DatabaseSloErrorProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("Annotation Started ");
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(DatabaseSloError.class)) {
            // Perform processing logic here
               System.out.println("Processing element with value: ");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration in build.gradle file

```
tasks.named('compileJava') {
        options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
        options.compilerArgs += ['-proc:only']
        options.compilerArgs += ['-processor', 'com.learn.restapi.annotation.DatabaseSloErrorProcessor']
    }
```

Error I am getting:

> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Annotation processor 'com.learn.restapi.annotation.DatabaseSloErrorProcessor' not found

Path for DatabaseSloErrorProcessor:

> java/com/learn/restapi/annotation/DatabaseSloErrorProcessor.java

Is there anything which I am missing here as processor is not getting called.